# Can't enable /sbin/ip with visudo

Tags: networking, permissions, ip

I'm trying to run the command `ip link set down dev wlan3` as the user `rescue`.

I'm trying to give `rescue` access to `/sbin/ip` by running `visudo` and adding this line:

```
rescue ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/ip
```

I then run the command again but still get back:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

How can I enable a user to run this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sudo command:

```
$ sudo ip link set down dev wlan3
```

Comment: The command is part of a larger program. We don't want to give the program full `sudo` permissions for security reasons.

Comment: then replace `/sbin/ip` with a shellscript contains `sudo /sbin/ip.real`.

Comment: nevermind I misunderstood `visudo`, calling with `sudo` I don't have to enter a password like normal.